# How to store and display an image in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem in storing and displaying image. The code doesn't work. I want to upload the image in the folder "img" and display it.

This is my code :

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="image" ><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

upload_file.php

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    if (file_exists("img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Comment: do you have obesession with 'O's?

Comment: Why don't youstore the path of the file instead of the image itself?

Comment: What is the error that you receive ??

Comment: @Poomrokc The 3years how to store the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you gave a different name for the file in the input file tag in your form.

Change this

```
<input type="file" name="image" ><br>
```

to this

```
<input type="file" name="file" ><br>
```

and it should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

You may also consider putting the contents in upload_file.php in an if-conditional to prevent it from execution on direct access as follows:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Your code here    
}
```

Comment: Sorry didnt work, it shows undefined index image, split(), link

Comment: Did you change the name of the input file tag to `'file'` ?

Comment: Because the error message itself says undefined index image... which means you have used the word image as a name / variable...

Comment: I even tried to run the code. It works fine after correcting the mistake, as suggested.

Comment: Ok it shows one message now which is "Invalid file"

Comment: if i may ask how and where i put that?

Comment: Put this `var_dump($_FILES);` in the second line after `<?php`.

Comment: it shows array (size=1)
  'file' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'Chrysanthemum.jpg' (length=17)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpB4B5.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 879394
Invalid file

Comment: Well... There you are... The size of the file is greater than the maximum limit, given by you. So either upload a file of a smaller size or increase the expected file size to let's say 20,00,000 (which is about approx. 1.9 MB)....

Comment: Well... Enjoy coding... Cheers... ;)